# How to edit a property list with multiple levels?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, property-list

I want to change a value in this Property List `profileData.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>profiles</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Default Profile</string>
            <key>size</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>length</key>
        <string>cm</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to set the integer of the key `size` to `1`. I've done this like this:

```
// reading Property List as described in Property List Programming Guide
NSError *error = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *plistPath;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                     NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"profileData.plist"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"profileData" ofType:@"plist"];
}
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                      propertyListWithData:plistXML
                                      options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                      format:&format
                                      error:&error];
if (!temp) {
    DNSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %ld", error, (long)format);
}

// getting the right dictionary
NSMutableArray *profiles = [temp objectForKey:@"profiles"];
NSMutableDictionary profile0 = [profiles objectAtIndex:0];

// Setting new integer
[profile0 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"size"];

// saving objects in reverse
[profiles replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:profile0];
[temp setObject:profiles forKey:@"profiles"];

// writing property list
[temp writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

This code works.

My question: is this the best way to do this? Reading the property list from disk is ok. But is it nessesary to save all "levels" of the property list in seperate mutable objects and after that to set all this objects in reverse up to the highest level of the property list?

For me it seems a little bit complicated to do this in that way even when I imagine a property list with more levels. It would be nice if it would be possible to do it in this way:

```
[temp setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKeyPath:@"profiles.0.size"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*The nature of using a plist or XML in XCode requires you to load the entire contents of the file into memory before doing anything with it (unless you're using a 3rd-party DOM parser for XML), just as you've done here. NSArray & NSDictionary then have the `writeToFile: atomically:` method you're already using to write changes back to disk. 

Of course you can access and change the temp NSMutableDictionary at whichever level you like, but if you want to save the changes then this is pretty much how you have to do it. 

As you imagined, this can be bad for larger/complex data or if you're saving changes all the time. 

I'd suggest you refactor this into multiple methods - right now you're loading the data, making the changes, AND writing back out to file all in the same place, which means you have to do all of that each time.

Break things up so you can do these tasks independently:

 - load plist from disk 
 - create temp copy of plist data as @property
 - make a change to tempdata @property (passing in whatever argument you need); 
 - write changes to disk

This would allow you to make multiple changes to the temp data as needed & only update the data model on disk when you have a bunch to do at once or need to ensure it's up to date (say, before the app goes into the background). This would cut the # of read/writes, but requires you to consider how fresh you need your data model to be & when's the best time to update the changes. 

If you're not stuck w/using plists, you could also look into using JSON, which is faster & lighter, and XCode now has pretty good native support, but writing to a file is the exact same process. For persisting larger, more complex data sets and making easier changes to individual items you might want to consider CoreData.   

..................................
1 other note ... In these lines: 

    NSMutableArray *profiles = [temp objectForKey:@"profiles"];
    NSMutableDictionary profile0 = [self.profiles objectAtIndex:0];

You're declaring `*profiles` within the method, not as a property of the object, so you shouldn't refer to it as `self.profiles`. Surprised this works w/o causing an error (unless you have both? In that case it won't work as expected). After refactoring to separate methods an @property is what you'll want.*/
```

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT BELOW:

I see - in that case, your suggestion above seems pretty close, but the method name is `setValue:(id) forKeyPath:(NSString *)`, not `setObject...` . Also, you can use the Obj-C literal syntax for NSNumber.

Maybe try something like:
    `[temp setValue:@1 forKeyPath:@"temp.profiles.0.size"];`

(Note: haven't tested this. Not sure if you need full path including `temp` in keyPath). 
See Apple's [KVC programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-178791) and [KVC Protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-CJBIBGAB)

I don't think this approach would have an appreciable impact on speed or performance, but I haven't tested it. This also assumes that the object you're accessing is definitely a dictionary w/those specific keys. If the structure or keys ever change there's no introspection or error handling here. A benefit of your initial approach is that you're being explicit about the object types & methods/properties they have access to, whereas this is kind of open-ended.

Comment: Good point, that I should do it with seperate methods. But my real question was if the is no other way to change the data in the lowest level then going through all levels before (`profile` > `profile0`), setting the data and then saving this all the way back?

Relating to your note: I compressed the code posted here a little bit and removed the properties I had in my original code. So, in my code `self.profiles` was correct an you're completely right, here it should be `profiles`. I've edited the code in my post.

Comment: Ok, edited above to answer that question more directly. I think you were on the right track w/your suggestion, but had incorrect method name. Haven't tested new response but it should get you closer. Since NSArrays store everything as "id" and won't know whether or not profile.0 is a dictionary, I'm not entirely sure how it'll react to asking for specific keys...